# use mathsf as default mathfont

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

Using `\mathsf` explicitly inside math environment, I can have `mathsf` (`Roboto light condensed` in this case) as a math font. I am looking for a way to get this as default, so that, I don't need to put `\mathsf` in each math environment.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[light,condensed]{roboto}
\begin{document}
Without Mathsf $C_6H_6$\\

With Mathsf  $\mathsf{C_6H_6}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: `roboto` is a *text* font, what you are seeing is Computer Modern sans serif math. Try `\textsf{ABC}$\mathsf{ABC}$`.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helpful?

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[light,condensed,sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
Without Mathsf $C_6H_6$\\

With Mathsf  $C_6H_6$
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is changing the normal text as well

Comment: @BaRud You might want to look at "1.2.3 sans in math" in the mathastext manual.